# ¿Cómo se originaron las expresiones tipo "¡A <verbo> se ha dicho!"?

Tags: gramática, verbos, modismos, expresiones

Las cosas en las que uno se fija viendo *La patrulla canina* con su hijo: el "grito de guerra" de Skye cada vez que la eligen para una misión es "¡A volar se ha dicho!".

La estructura

> ¡A <verbo> se ha dicho!

es bastante usada, pero me suena como una frase que a alguien se le ocurrió una vez (usada con un verbo concreto), y que tuvo un cierto éxito y la gente empezó a copiar y a usar con otros verbos. Ejemplo:

> *—¡A callar se ha dicho! —gritó el cojo, vendedor de La Semana—. Aquí se viene a lo que se viene, y a guardar la circuspición.*
>
> Benito Pérez Galdós, "Misericordia", 1897 (España).

¿Es esto así? ¿Se puede determinar el origen de esta estructura gramatical? No encuentro ningún caso en el CORDE de antes de finales del siglo XIX (el más antiguo es de 1887), por lo que parece que fue algo que surgió de repente.

Answer (score 5):

No sé hasta que punto se puede datar el origen de esta expresión o incluso su primer uso registrado.

Lo más probable es que se originase a través del habla coloquial. Si fue a través de un proceso "viral" (se le ocurrió a alguien y otros lo copiaron, como tú propones) o si diversos hablantes caían en los mismo coloquialismos de forma independiente es algo que quizá no podemos llegar a saber.

Lo que sí sabemos es que [el infinitivo puede usarse como imperativo <sub>(RAE)</sub>](http://www.rae.es/consultas/infinitivo-por-imperativo)

> Solo es válido el empleo del infinitivo con valor de imperativo dirigido a una segunda persona del singular o del plural cuando aparece precedido de la preposición a, uso propio de la lengua oral coloquial: ¡Tú, a callar!; Niños, a domir.

Este uso viene, según la RAE, "del habla coloquial". Hay que tener también en cuenta que, aunque sea un mal uso, el infinitivo es usado como imperativo sin la forma "a + infinitivo".

Así que de un "¡Tú, calla!" podemos pasar a un

> ¡Tú, (se te ha mandado) (a) callar!

La construcción "Mandar a + infinitivo" puede tener también el significado de "[ordenar a alguien hacer algo <sub>(Fundeu)</sub>](http://www.fundeu.es/consulta/mandar-buscar-330/)", no solo de "enviar a alguien a un sitio".

A esta estructura podríamos añadir el "se ha dicho" para añadir refuerzo.

> Callad niños. Se os ha mandado (a) callar. A callar se ha dicho!

Y de esta suerte de locución que es un imperativo tenemos la forma general que es simplemente una exhortación tipo "Vamos todos a hacer esto".

Comment: Me ha recordado lo de [_Si me queréis, irse_](http://www.rtve.es/alacarta/videos/personajes-en-el-archivo-de-rtve/lola-flores-estalla-boda-lolita-si-quereis-irse/2991266/).